# Printing MySQL data to textbox

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I apologize before I speak English very little I want to write all of the data in textboxes, but I could not do it

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "vipser"; 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM `a_info` WHERE `pax`='" . $_GET['pax'] . "' and `nereden`='" . $_GET['durum'] . "' and `nereye`='" . $_GET['gdurum'] . "'");
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['pax'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['a_cinsi'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nereden'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nereye'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['saat'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['km'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['fiyat'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><img src="' . $row["a_resmi"] . '" width="75" height="75"/></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: Where are the text boxes?

Comment: do you mean like : echo "<td><input type='text' value=' " . $row['pax'] . "' /></td>"; ?

Answer (score 1):

Store the data of the loop in a variable instead of echoing and then assign the variable into textbox's value. Done this here:

```
<?php
$str = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
        $str .= . $row['pax'] . " " . $row['a_cinsi'] . " " . $row['nereden'] .  " " . $row['nereye'] . " " . $row['saat'] . " " . $row['km'] . " " . $row['fiyat'] . " ";
    }
}
?>
<input type="text" value="<?= $str ?>" />
```

You can put this input inside while if you want different textboxes for each row.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\vipser\git.php on line 35

Comment: @AliŞenyil by mistake the code isn't pasted properly. Lemme redo it.